# ZK dynamic rows and column listbox, with sort exception

Tags: sorting, dynamic, listbox, zk

I am attempting to build the *minimum* acceptable solution to a dynamic zk listbox (mysql table) renderer. I have the basic functionality in place:  Given a table name, the zk listbox will correctly render the columns and rows - that part works fine.

However, when sorting I get "[Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable".

Please note this is meant only for *me* to learn the internal plumbing of zk and serve as a simple demonstrator. For me, the "best" solution is the simplest and the shortest. But I'm at the point where I don't know what I don't know.

Here is my table.zul file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<zk xmlns="http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zul">
   <div apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer"
                    viewModel="@id('vm') @init('com.anclad.DynamicColumnModel')"
            >
                    <label value="Select Table: " />
                    <combobox id="table_list" model="@load(vm.getTableList())" autodrop="true" />
                    <button id="loadTableButton" label="Load Table" />
                    <label value="Currently Selected Table: " />
                    <label value="@bind(vm.tableName)" />
                    <listbox
                            id="inboxGrid"
                            itemRenderer="com.anclad.DynamicListitemRenderer"
                            height="800px"
                            mold="paging" pageSize="100"
                            hflex="1" vflex="true"
                            model="@load(vm.getTableData())"
                    >
                            <listhead
                                    menupopup="auto"
                            >
                                    <listheader
                                            forEach="${vm.columnList}"
                                            label="${each}"
                                            sort="auto"
                                    ></listheader>
                            </listhead>
                    </listbox>
            </div>
</zk>
```

And here is my DynamicColumnModel.java:

```
package com.anclad;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.*;

import org.zkoss.zul.ListModel;
import org.zkoss.zul.ListModelExt;
import org.zkoss.zul.event.ListDataListener;

import java.sql.*;

import org.zkoss.bind.annotation.Init;

public class DynamicColumnModel implements ListModelExt, ListModel
{

    private SchemaConnector sc = new SchemaConnector();
    private List<String> columnList = new ArrayList<String>();

    private TableConnector tc = new TableConnector();

    @Init
    public void init()
    {
            columnList = tc.getColumnList();
    }

    public List<String> getColumnList()
    {
            return columnList;
    }

    public void setColumnList(List<String> columnList)
    {
            this.columnList = columnList;
    }

    public String getTableName ()
    {
            return tc.getTableName();
    }

    public List<String> getTableList()
    {
            List<String> list = sc.getList();
            return list;
    }

    public ArrayList<String[]> getTableData()
    {
            return tc.getList();
    }

    public void sort(Comparator cmpr, boolean ascending)
    {
             //do the real sorting...
            //notify the listbox (or grid) that data is changed by use of ListDataEvent...
            System.out.println("entered sort");
            //would actually like to send the sort column name back to let the db do the sort...
    }

    public String getSortDirection (Comparator cmpr)
    {
            System.out.println("entered getSortDirection");
            return null;
    }

    public void removeListDataListener(ListDataListener l)
    {
            System.out.println("entered removeListDataListenter");

    }

    public void addListDataListener(ListDataListener l)
    {
            System.out.println("entered addListDataListener");

    }

    public int getSize()
    {
            System.out.println("entered getSize");
            return 33;
    }

    public String[] getElementAt(int index)
    {
            System.out.println("entered getElementAt");
            return null;
    }
}
```

I have a DynamicListitemRenderer class as well, I don't want to post it here unless necessary. I don't think it's relevant to my sort exception, however.

The SchemaConnector and TableConnector classes encapsulate the mysql/jdbc logic:  the first returns a list of tables, and the latter returns the data ("select * from ....")

Obviously, the interface methods are stubs, but as far as I can tell the code is not getting that far.

Just wondering if someone out there can tell me what the next step is. I would like only for the default listbox sort functionality to work correctly.  Ideally, I would like to have the database query do the sorting, so I need to pass the column name back thru the stack (somehow) but for now, any solution that moves me forward is fine.

Comment: As of version 6.0.0 `ListModelExt` is deprecated, use `Sortable` instead. Also the error is a bit odd because `String` actually implements `Comparable`. Can you use the debugger to identify where the cast exception is thrown?

Comment: Can you point the exact line of the zul that throws the exception?